# My CNN is over-fitting even in simple architecture and lots of data

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have created a CNN for multi-labelled images, (of different shoes) and their size is 100x100x3. I have 50000 images,with 5 classes (which I think are enough), but the issue is, while training:

- Both test accuracy and validation accuracy rise together in the start but Val acc becomes almost constant at 58% approx, and the train acc keeps on increasing up to 85-99% approx.
- seems like over fitting, I have tried using drop outs, l1 regularization etc.

Here is my architecture. What could be wrong with this?

```
**Conv Layer , 16 ,(3,3), input =100,100,3 ,padding = same**
**LeakyRelu and MaxPooling()**
**Dropouts **
**Conv layer , 32, (9,9), pd = same** 
**LeakyRelu and maxpooling()**
**Dropouts**
**Flatten()**
**Dense 5, leakyRelu, l1(0.001), dropout**
**Dense 5, leakyRelu,l1(0.001)**
**Sigmoid**
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

- a filter of size `9x9` is not that common, certainly not for such small images. I'd use `3x3` in that case
- have you tried just using ReLU instead of its leaky version? I think it's better to start with the simple version of a nonlinearity and later on try different versions to see which performs best (and if there *is* any difference)
- I would drop the L1 regularizations and only add them later on to see if they help. First try to get reasonable results before you try to get state of art results
- currently you have a dropout after each layer, which seems to be a lot to me. Maybe you can try removing the first one? Also: what are your dropout rates?
- you have a pooling layer after each convolutional layer, have you tried removing the first one? As with the dropouts, you seem to be over-using the pooling layers.
- your first fully-connected (dense) layer has very few nodes. Note that the output of the `Flatten()` layer is 20000-dimensional (twice pooling -> `100/2/2 x 100/2/2 x 32 = 20000`) so it would make more sense to use a larger number of nodes in the layer between the flatten and the last fully-connected. I would suggest to try 1024 or even 256 would be better I guess.

Also you have very little convolutional layers. Even for the CIFAR-10 dataset (60000 images of size `32x32x3` for 10 classes) I would use at least 2 blocks of 2 convolutional layers each, something like this:

```
input(32, 32, 3)

conv_2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')
conv_2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')
dropout(0.25)
maxpooling

conv_2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')
conv_2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')
dropout(0.25)
maxpooling

flatten
dense(1024, activation='relu')
dense(10, activation='sigmoid')
```